# Get part of a string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, substring

HTML code:

```
<div id="block-id-45"></div>
```

How can I get number **"45"** of string using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)?

Comment: You already know 45, what is the pattern you are looking for?.. jQuery can help you get the div element, if you know the name (or part of the name), if you want to rip apart the string, then use the language for split/regex etc.

Comment: @Quintin - I'm assuming the pattern is the beginning of the ID ... something like `block-id-`.

Comment: He was not looking for a pattern , just wanted to get a part of that pattern and answer with high up ratios doesn't answer this. He just asks "How i can get number "45" of string "

Comment: Since your id looks like block-id-45, $(this).attr("id").split("-")[2] will return number 45 when $(this) return your target div element.

Answer (score 31):

To **return the number at the end of an `id` attribute** use

```
$(this).attr("id").match(/[\d]+$/);
```

The above will return `45` if `$(this)` is `<div id="block-id-45"></div>`

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxLuK/)

The way the above works is that you retrieve the id of the element using **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**, then you look at the `id` and use **[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** to recover the number at the end of it. `/[\d]+$/` is a regex. `[\d]` means one digit `+` means one or more (of the digits). and `$` means the end of the line.

---

You can use this function to retrieve the numbers from the end of all divs with an id that starts with `block-id-` by making use of the **[attribute starts with selector `[name^=value]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** and **[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**:

### Practical usage:

```
$(function() {

      // Select all DIS that start with 'block-id-'
      //   and iterate over each of them.
    $("div[id^='block-id-']").each(function() {

          // You could push this data to an array instead.
          // This will display it.
        $("body").append( "Id number: " + 
                            // This is the number at the end
                          $(this).attr("id").match(/[\d]+$/) +
                          "<br/>" );
    });
});​
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3V5CG/)**

Answer (score 8):

You don't need (or particularly want) jQuery for this (it's very useful for lots of *other* things, just not particularly for this). Straight JavaScript and DOM:

```
var div = document.getElementById('block-id-45');
var n = div.id.lastIndexOf('-');
var target = div.id.substring(n + 1);
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/osozu

If you're already using jQuery, you can replace the first line with:

```
var div = $('#block-id-45')[0];
```

...but there's little if any reason to.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), simply:

```
$("[id='block-id-45']").attr("id").split("-")[2]
```

For all block-id-##, you can use mask pattern from [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722360/jquery-get-part-of-string/3722418#3722418):

```
$("[id^='block-id-']").click(function(){

    row_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[2];
    .............
    .............
})
```