# How to get a portion an element's text value

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="search_tbl_info" class="dataTables_info">Showing 1 to 20 of 62 entries</div>
```

Where 62 will be changing from user to user.
It could be 0 or it could be 2,431 and anything in between.
Also worth noting is that if there are only 5 entries it would read:

```
<div id="search_tbl_info" class="dataTables_info">Showing 1 to 5 of 5 entries</div>
```

So there are several values that could be changing.

How do I use jQuery to get the number value of 62 in the first example?
Or 2,431 or 5 or whatever the value is?

Thanks!

Comment: So it will look like `<div id="search_tbl_info" class="dataTables_info">12</div>` ? Or contain some text in it too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get part of a string using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722360/get-part-of-a-string-using-jquery)

Comment: A better approach would be to output that value somewhere else when you output it from the database, and then grab it from there.

Comment: Assuming this is datatables plugin, the values can be accessed from the plugin API. But it depends on which version you are using as the API went through some changes recently

Answer (score 1):

If you have this particular form of text

You can use:

```
var text = $('#search_tbl_info').text();
console.log(text.substring(text.indexOf('of') + 3, text.length - 8));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/73j28wz3/)

Answer (score 0):

**Data-atributes**
A way to do this is add `data-` attributes. 
I prefer this way of working because if you need to change the text you don't have to change your code. (And think of multiple languages for an example)

```
<div id="search_tbl_info" class="dataTables_info" data-start="1" data-to="20" data-total="62">Showing 1 to 20 of 62 entries</div>
```

Now you can access that values by:

```
$("#search_tbl_info").attr('data-start/data-to/data-total')
```

or:

```
$("#search_tbl_info").data('start/to/total')
```

If you want the whole text you need:

```
$("#search_tbl_info").text()
```

(no data attributes needed)

**Span**
Another way is putting spans around the numbers. Like:

```
<div id="search_tbl_info" class="dataTables_info">Showing <span clas="from">1</span> to <span clas="to">20 </span>of <span clas="total">62</span> entries</div>
```

And you can access them by:

```
$('#search_tbl_info .from').text()
$('#search_tbl_info .to').text()
$('#search_tbl_info .total').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply grabbing the text, splitting the text string by the spaces and taking the 5th index of the array returned. It would look something like the following:

```
// Together
var text = (($('#search_tbl_info').text()).split(' '))[5];

// Broken Out
var text = $('#search_tbl_info').text();
text = text.split(' ');
text = text[5];
```

Note that this solution works because in both scenarios, the total number (which is the desired number in this case) is appears to always be the 6th part of the string (excluding spaces). This correlates to position `5` in a `0` index based array.

**Important:** If the verbiage in the `<div>` ever changes or the total number shifts within the string, this solution will fall apart as it's based on the exact index.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/kac9bb2a/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

i think if the string remains in the same format i.e.

> Showing **Numeric** to **Numeric** of **Numeric** entries

then we can use the following code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var div_string = $('#search_tbl_info').text();
        var Total_Count = sd.substring(sd.lastIndexOf("of") + 3, sd.lastIndexOf(" entries"));
        alert(Total_Count)
    });
```

the variable **Total_Count** contains the count required.